# DataprocClusterCreateOperator doesnt have temp_bucket variable to define

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, dataproc

I am trying to create dataproc cluster via DataprocClusterCreateOperator via Apache airflow
Airflow version:    1.10.15
Composer version: 1.16.4
I wanted to assign a temp-bucket used by project to the cluster and not the bucket google creates during run time. This option is available when we create cluster via command line using option --temp-bucket but this same variable is not available to pass via ClusterCreateOperator.

Dataproc operator info:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.15/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/dataproc_operator.html

create cluster via command:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create cluster-name \
    --properties=core:fs.defaultFS=gs://defaultFS-bucket-name \
    --region=region \
    --bucket=staging-bucket-name \
    **--temp-bucket=project-owned-temp-bucket-name \** 
    other args ...
```

```
create_cluster = DataprocClusterCreateOperator(
        task_id="create_cluster",
        project_id="my-project_id",
        cluster_name="my-dataproc-{{ ds_nodash }}",
        num_workers=2,
        storage_bucket="project_bucket",
    region="us-east4",
       ... other params...
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the method [`DataprocClusterCreateOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.15/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/dataproc_operator.html#:%7E:text=%5Bdocs%5Dclass%20DataprocClusterCreateOperator(DataprocOperationBaseOperator)%3A) in Ariflow doesn’t support the property `temp-bucket`. You can use this property only with the [`gcloud command` or `REST API`](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/staging-bucket#rest-api).

With `REST API`, you can use these fields `ClusterConfig.configBucket` and `ClusterConfig.tempBucket` in a `cluster.create`.

A Possible solution could be creating a `scheduler job`. You can see this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/using-scheduler).

Comment: @naval if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.